# Threading in C#: .join obligotory?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am just learning about Threads in C# and a question arose.

I have a TCP-Server-Class which accepts connections and passes them to a TCP-Client-Class.
The code roughly looks like this:  *(dummy code)*

```
Class TcpServer
{
    public static Main(string[] args)
    {
       while(true)
       {    
          //I create a new instance of my "TCP-Client-Class" and pass the accepted connection to the constructor
          ConnectionHandler client = new ConnectionHandler(TCPListner.acceptconnections);

          //create a new Thread to handle that connection
          Thread client1 = new Thread (client.handleConnection()); //and start handling it
          client.start;

          //Do some other stuff for protokolling
          do.someOtherStuff;
       // and then wait for a new connection
       }
    }    
    //Some other Methods etc.
}

Class ConnectionHandler
{
   //Constructor in which a connection TCPclient connection has to be passed
   public ConnectionHandler(TCPclient client)
   {
      //Do stuff
   }
   
   //Method to handle connection
   public void handleConnections()
   {
      //Open streams
      //.
      //.
      //.
      //close streams
      //close connections
    }
}
```

Now to my questions:
a) Is it obligatory to close that Thread again, after it reached the "close connection" part?
b) To close a thread do I just have to call the .join Method in my main class or is there anything else I have to take care about.
c) Incase of an error, can I just simply leave the "handleConnection()" method and close that thread (ofc with appropriate error-handling)?
d) Is it important to drop the "client" reference or the "client1" reference? Or is it just consumed by the garbage collector?

Comment: Maybe for educational purposes it is interesting to work with Thread classes directly, but for other purposes I woul recommend you to take a look to Thread Pools or even to the Async feature in C#6

Comment: @Rafa okay thats the second time I've read Thread pools, i will definatly read upon it now :D

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's entirely fine to let the thread just complete normally. If the top-level call of a thread throws an exception, it may take down the process, depending on how the CLR is configured. It's usually better to have a top-level error handler to log the error and move on.

However, you should consider what you want to happen on shutdown:

- Your `while (true)` loop should be changed to allow some mechanism for shutting down
- If you keep track of all the threads currently handling existing requests, when you know you're trying to shut down, you can `Join` on them (probably with a timeout) to allow them to complete before the server finishes. However, you want to remove a thread from that collection when it completes. This sort of thing gets fiddly fairly quickly, but is definitely doable.

As an aside, it's more common to use a thread-pool for this sort of thing, rather than creating a brand new thread for each request.

Comment: What is CLR :D  And by Thread-Pool you mean an array of threads right?
(That's what i've done in the "proper" code, and ofc there is a mechanism to stop accepting connections. This is still just a dummy code to help me make my code more obvious :)) PS: Thanks for the answer

Comment: So... in conclusion you are saying, that a Thread terminates itself when it reached the "end of it's code" without having to to close it with .join. correct?

Comment: @MilesA.: To understand the terms "CLR" and "thread-pool" I suggest you do normal research - read books, do web searches etc. But yes, there's no need to join a thread... there's no concept of "closing" it.

Comment: already am doing that :D Thanks allot for your helps anyways :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Wouldn't the best way to ensure thread termination on app shutdown just be to set  `thread.IsBackground = true`?

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis: The point is to do it in a *graceful* way - to give requests up to a few seconds to complete. Now you could do that by just sleeping for a few seconds in the main thread, admittedly... but that would delay shutdown unnecessarily, which could be a pain if you're planning to restart.